# error in clearing error provider message when user input is valid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I have this code for errorprovider. However, its doesn't clear whenever a valid input is given.

```
public void NotEmpty(Control c)
{
    ErrorProvider err = new ErrorProvider();
    if (c.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        err.Clear();
        //err.SetError(c, "");
    }
    else if(c.Text == String.Empty) err.SetError(c, "Field cannot be empty");
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NotEmpty(tbName);
}
```

Here are some links I checked and it had no effect with mine.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570654/clear-error-provider-message-when-user-input-change-to-valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570654/clear-error-provider-message-when-user-input-change-to-valid/)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858888/problem-with-errorprovider-clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858888/problem-with-errorprovider-clear/)

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be59f63e-234a-4d62-8f05-317d1887f5c0/errorprovider-how-can-i-remove-errorprovider-icon-when-error-is-corrected?forum=winforms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be59f63e-234a-4d62-8f05-317d1887f5c0/errorprovider-how-can-i-remove-errorprovider-icon-when-error-is-corrected?forum=winforms/)

If the field is initially filled, it won't bring out error message but if its(the field) cleared and filled again, it won't clear error message.

Comment: possibly cos you are creating a new errorprovider, and the old one is still lurking around. hence you're clearing the new one, not the old one

Comment: It worked perfectly @BugFinder . I instantiate the errorprovider in the class itself.